# What does the [0,0] expression do?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this line:

```
theta1 = zeros((3,2)) #this is a 3x2 matrix
theta0 = zeros((2,1)) #this is a 2x1 matrix
thetares = theta1.dot(theta0) #3x2 * 2x1 -> 3x1

res0 = thetares.T.dot(thetares)[0,0] #result 0.0
res1 = thetares.T.dot(thetares)      #result [[0.]]
```

but I dont know, what does this **[0,0]** at the end of the expression of **res0**. res0 and res1 result will be a 1x1 matrix

Comment: [0, 0] means you look at the element on row 0, column 0

Comment: It takes the element at position (0, 0), thus returning the only element as a scalar. Exactly as you see in your output.

Comment: You may need to read up on Python list and NumPy array indexing.

Comment: res0 is not exactly a 1x1 matrix. it is the first element of the resultant matrix after the dot operation

Comment: res1 should be pretty clear, once you realize that `.T` does exactly what you would think it does and remember that A.T * A = I_n. For matrices A and the n-dimensional identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the dot product of the transpose of thetares and thetares might produce a double dimensional numpy array. So to take the first value from that result of dot product which is at the index [0,0].
The best way to understand this is by removing [0,0] part from res0 and compare the result.

Answer (score 1):

res1 is the matrix (1x1 matrix) after the dot product operation. As per the code, res0 is the element at position(0,0) of res1.